# Using pointers to member to pass member function as arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, function-binding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Foo 
{
    public:
    Foo(int value)
    : value_(value){}
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "member print: " << value_ << std::endl;
    }
    int value_;
};

void print()
{
    std::cout << "stand alone print" << std::endl;
}

template<typename F>
void execute(F&& f)
{
    f();
}

int main()
{ 

    execute(print);

    Foo foo(5);

    auto binded = std::bind(&Foo::print,foo);
    execute(binded);

    //auto Foo::* foo_print = &Foo::print;
    //execute(foo.*foo_print);

}
```

The code above compiles and runs fine.

But if the last part, which uses the pointers to the print member function, is uncommented, then compilation fails with:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function of type ‘void (Foo::)()’
```

Is there a syntax error in the code, or is this an impossibility for some reason?

Comment: An actual pointer to a member function is, at the assembly level, the same as a pointer to an ordinary function. Therefore, to call it, you must somehow bind the object.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve there? `Foo::print` requires an object to be called on, because it is not static. With `foo.*foo_print` you still would only get that member function, but not bound to an object.

Comment: @t.niese intuitively, I tought the "foo." of  "foo.*foot_print" could be the part binding the function.

Comment: @Vince if that would be the case `std::bind` would not require `foo` as a separate parameter

Comment: @Slava you may note that pointers to members applied to non-function members do "bind" using the proposed syntax, e.g. "int Foo::* pointer = &Foo::_value; std::cout << foo.*pointer << std::endl; " does print the value of the instance foo.

Comment: @Vince so how it changed what I said before? C++ does not support such "binding" so you cannot use it this way. Otherwise you could pass it to `std::bind` this way.

Comment: A non-static member variable will have a unique address for every instance of the class. The member functions will not (necessarily/conceptually). Think of a member function having one address only no matter how many instances of the class you create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a non-static member function to execute, because it depends on the `this` element (and so it needs an invocation object), instead you can use a `lambda`:

```
execute([&](){foo.print();});
```