# Pass member function as function pointer to argument

Tags: c++, arduino, function-pointers, member-functions

Here is my Code:
I want to use a class inside my custom MyStateMachine. I do not want to inherit de StateMachine class as I just want to use it with its functions. The MyStateMachine class is only to encapsulate a few things.

MyStateMachine.h

```
#include <StateMachine.h>

class MyStateMachine {
 public:
    void Initialisation();

 private:
    StateMachine machine = StateMachine();
    State* m0Initialisation = machine.addState(&Initialisation); // problem here
};
```

MyStateMachine.cpp

```
#include "MyStateMachine.h"

void MyStateMachine::Initialisation() {
   // do initialisation stuff here
}
```

machine.addState expects a function pointer as argument:
`State* addState(void (*functionPointer)());`

I get the following error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'StateMachine::addState(void (MyStateMachine::*)())
note: State* StateMachine::addState(void (*)())
     State* addState(void (*functionPointer)());
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void (MyStateMachine::*)()' to 'void (*)()'
Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'StateMachine::addState(void (MyStateMachine::*)())'
```

If I define the function outside the class, I can successfully pass this function as a function pointer (`&Initialization`).
I guess it has something to do that it is a function of a class and it needs the reference to the object. But even with that I did not find a solution.

How could I pass the function? If possible without external libraries (e.g. std::bind).

I have looked at a few posts but could not find a proper solution.

- [pass-an-objects-member-function-as-argument-function-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400905/pass-an-objects-member-function-as-argument-function-pointer)
- [class-member-function-as-function-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195579/class-member-function-as-function-pointer)
- [using-pointers-to-member-to-pass-member-function-as-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403304/using-pointers-to-member-to-pass-member-function-as-arguments)

Comment: It's not possible even with `std` library (which is not external) or any other library. Member function and free function are different types. The former requires a pointer or reference to object on which it will be called. Since `void (*)()` doesn't accept any arguments, there's no way to pass anything along the function.

Comment: I think what @Yksisarvinen is trying to say is that member functions always have an implicit first argument, which is a pointer or reference to an instance of the class. This is the main difference between a normal function pointer and a member function pointer. So taking the implicit argument into account, the member function is not a void nullary function with signature `void (*)()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some different solutions to your problem.

1: Change the type of your funciton pointer in Statemachine::addState(...) to be a function pointer to a *member* type instead of a function pointer to a *non* member function.

Check out section "Pointers to members" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)

2: Use `std::function` as the type of `addState` and do

```cpp
State* m0Initialisation = machine.addState([this]() {Initialisation(); });
```

3: Change Initialization to be static and send in a pointer to your class every time you call the function.

```
static void Initialisation(StateMachine &self);
```

Comment: Regarding your second solution: If `StateMachine` can be modified, it would be better to make `addState` a funciton template accpeting any callable type. The type-erasing capabilities of `std::function` are not really needed here.

Comment: @joergbrech Then you are assuming that addState calls the function directly. If you are storing function pointers of different types that solution would not work.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, in the latter case `StateMachine` would have to be a template class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `StateMachine::addState` expects a normal function pointer, which is different from a member function pointer. You can make your `Initialization` function static. Then the member function pointer is essentially a normal function pointer:

```cpp
struct State {};

struct StateMachine {
    State* addState (void (*)()){ return nullptr; }
};

class MyStateMachine {
 public:
    static void Initialisation();

 private:
    StateMachine machine = StateMachine();
    State* m0Initialisation = machine.addState(&Initialisation); // no problem here
};
```

Member functions always have an implicit first argument, which is a pointer or reference to an instance of the class. This is the main difference between a normal function pointer and a member function pointer. So taking the implicit argument into account, the member function is not a void nullary function with signature `void (*)(). Static member functions do not have an implicit first argument, so member function pointers to static member functions can be treated like normal function pointers.